# FastAPI: How to send data with websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, redis, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application that needs to send data to the frontend with websockets. The data is received from another application by listening a Redis pubsub channel. I'm totally amateur with websockets and not sure how should I proceed with this task. Here is what I've tried:

I have a function that connects to a Redis channel and listens to it. Is it possible to send data from this function to some websocket endpoint so that frontend could receive them?

```
from websockets import connect
from app.db.redis import pubsub

async def get_redis_msg():
    subscribe = pubsub.pubsub()
    subscribe.psubscribe("test_channel")
    while True:
        msg = subscribe.get_message()
        print(f"New message: {msg['data']}")
       
        # Is this possible?
        async with connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws") as websocket:
            await websocket.send("Hello world!")
```

Another option I've been trying to do is to use a websocket endpoint like this:

```
from redis import Redis
from app.db.redis import pubsub

pubsub = Redis()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()

        ps = pubsub.pubsub()
        ps.psubscribe('test_channel')
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

This one fails because for some reason it can't connect to Redis. Running this as a separate script without websocket and endpoint -stuff runs perfectly and subscribes to the `test_channel`. Any ideas how to continue with this?

Comment: i use redis in fast api without issue. are you sure your socket setup is functional? fastapi has docs for this: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/. 

if you can post the actual errors you are getting that will be helpful as well.

Comment: I use Redis also and excluding this, without issues. The main problem is, I don't know websockets well enough to know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Chris Yes, at least partially. Thank you.